# .net Code-Comments visible in final program?

Tags: .net, comments, visible

i want to know if the entered comments in .net-Code (Visual Studio) like // this is a comment or ' this is a comment will be visible in the final program?

(Or could be made visible).

I already searched for it on google.

Thanks guys!

Comment: visible in what way?

Comment: @TGH decompile I assume

Comment: @Steve Yes, exactly. I mean i don't plan to store any secure information there, but i want to do some documentary things, but i don't want others to get them to see.

Comment: No, they are completely removed by the compiler.  Along with names of constants and local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: NO, it won't. Compiler would try to minimize the size of the compiled program by doing anything it could. Lets say you got an `if (false)` statement in your code the compiler would just remove that completely. So comments which is completely useless for execution would definitely not be in the compiled program.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are not part of compiled code.  This question is duplicate of [Comments and Compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821510/comments-compiled-into-exe-in-net)