# Checking if a url exist, not working for some urls

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am checking if a url exist, using HttpWebRequest. 
The problem, it's not working for some url's. 

Example: 

http://www.gkrs.no/ 

https://www.politi.no/kripos/statistikk/narkotika/

These url's exist. But show up in the code as not existing. 
It is working for most of the url's i am checking, its just these two that are causing some issues. Does anyone have any examples of what i still need to check for. Maybe there is something different in their headers.

I have tried both GET and HEAD request methods.

I am still new to programming and might need a simpler explanation. Sorry for bad English, not my first language.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
internal static bool IsValidLenke(string url){

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            return false;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            response.Close();
            return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Any exception will returns false.
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "not working"?  And why are you swallowing any and all exceptions without examining them?

Comment: The first url does not return 404, the second url has an SSL issue that you will never recognise as you ignore exceptions.

Comment: log your exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491213/logging-exception-in-c-sharp

Comment: this isn't a fool proof solution.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added a log exception. It seems like these two return 403 forbidden. Is it possible to check if a 403 forbidden, site exist. Or does all 403 sites exist ? Could a 403 site not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gkrs.no/ blocks you because you don't supply a valid user agent.
https://www.politi.no/kripos/statistikk/narkotika/  does not accept "HEAD", and then sends you a wild ride of redirects, so you need a cookie container to avoid being caught in an infinite loop.

Do something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 100;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.Method = "GET";                
request.UserAgent = " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
response.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working. Just a quick question. Will this also work for other links that have a status of 403 forbidden?

Comment: Probably, since very few sites will return 403 for a GET on the root.

Comment: Thanks again Mikael, your explanations helped me a lot.